# unclear pandas merge error

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two dataframes like the ones below.  I’m trying to merge them on the common field user_id.  I’ve checked the syntax and I can not see what the issue is.  I’m running python 2.7.  Does anyone see the issue?

Code:

```
print s_data.columns

Index([u'user_id', u'bdn', u'preference_bdn'], dtype='object')


print data.columns

Index([u'user_id', u'bdn', u'preference_bdn'], dtype='object')


pd.merge[s_data, data, how='inner',left_on='user_id', right_on='user_id'].head()
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-55-820f93556a69>", line 3
    pd.merge[s_data, data how='inner',left_on='user_id', right_on='user_id'].head()
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Data:

```
print s_data.head()

   user_id       bdn  preference_bdn
0  4104910        vfs              0.95
1  4282779        vfs              1.00
2  5125665        MAIDE            0.65
3  5125665        SP               0.43
4  5125665        DK               0.11

print data.head()

   user_id              bdn  preference_bdn
0  3949334             M                   0.37
1  3949334             RAC.                0.37
2  3949334             B                   0.19
3  3949334             TAY                 0.19
4  4105144             AL                  0.68
```

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner',on='user_id').head()` it should be work

Comment: Looks like you forgot a comma between `data how='inner'`

Comment: @Wen Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a comma between data and how. Use this -

```
s_data.merge(data, how = 'inner', on ='user_id')
```